# NullPointerException: null

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, null

What caused `NullPointerException`: null? I have no idea about it, my laptop just installed android studio, after I import my project, it can't run because of this. Not problems of the project I think because it runs normally in my PC.

```
null
java.lang.NullPointerException



java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument 0 for @NotNull parameter of com/intellij/util/ui/UIUtil.isFocusAncestor must not be null
    at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.isFocusAncestor(UIUtil.java)
    at com.intellij.ui.content.impl.ContentManagerImpl.isSelectionHoldsFocus(ContentManagerImpl.java:558)
    at com.intellij.ui.content.impl.ContentManagerImpl.setSelectedContent(ContentManagerImpl.java:513)
    at com.intellij.ui.content.impl.ContentManagerImpl.setSelectedContentCB(ContentManagerImpl.java:496)
    at com.intellij.ui.content.impl.ContentManagerImpl.setSelectedContentCB(ContentManagerImpl.java:485)
    at com.intellij.ui.content.impl.ContentManagerImpl.setSelectedContentCB(ContentManagerImpl.java:569)
    at com.intellij.ui.content.impl.ContentManagerImpl.setSelectedContent(ContentManagerImpl.java:574)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.invoker.GradleTasksExecutor.showMessages(GradleTasksExecutor.java:651)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.invoker.GradleTasksExecutor.access$1600(GradleTasksExecutor.java:106)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.invoker.GradleTasksExecutor$3$2.run(GradleTasksExecutor.java:326)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:319)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:744)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:714)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:697)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:524)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:335)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Answer (score 0):

The declaration of the method that is giving you a null is.

```
public static boolean isFocusAncestor(@NotNull final JComponent component);
```

so, try to check if `component` has value.

Comment: May I know where to find isFocusAncestor?

Comment: It is in the class com/intellij/util/ui/UIUtil.